# Adding class to primary-nav link when on a sub-page based on the url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have primary navigation that are just "in-page" links on the home page. I also have a section of three pages for pricing that live as sub-pages with the urls: /pricing/basic-pricing.html, /pricing/pro-pricing.html and /pricing/pricing-premium.html.

On those three pages, I have a side-nav to get back-and-forth between those pages. So two navigation elements (primary-nav and side nav). When on a sub-page i.e. /pricing/basic-pricing.html, I would like the primary-nav link called "pricing" to have an active class.

I have it working with the code below, but was wondering if there is a better way in case I add more sub-pages in the future. I don't want to have to add more jQuery just to accommodate a new page. Right now it's only looking to see if the url contains the string 'pricing' in the href and then it adds the class to the 'pricing' link in the primary nav.

```
<nav class="primary-nav">
<ul class="menu collapse vertical large-horizontal">
   <li><a href="#features">features</a></li>
   <li><a href="#options">options</a></li>
   <li><a href="#pricing">pricing</a></li>
   <li><a href="#testimonials">testimonials</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

```
<ul class="vertical menu side-nav">
    <li><a href="{{root}}pricing/basic-pricing.html">Basic Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{root}}pricing/pro-pricing.html">Pro Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{root}}pricing/premium-pricing.html">Premium Pricing</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.side-nav.menu a.is-active[href*="pricing"]').each(function () {
    $('.primary-nav .menu a[href$=pricing]').addClass('is-active');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `location` global object to detect which `url` or `uri` you're in,
here a link t it documentation : [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) 
example:

```
console.log(location.pathname) 
// /questions/56091860/adding-class-to-primary-nav-link-when-on-a-sub-page-based-on-the-url
```

in you case

```
// /pricing/basic-pricing.html
```